# WCF webHttpBinding out parameters support

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest, webhttpbinding

i am creating my first wcf service with `webHttpBinding`. On the net, i have read lot of articled telling that its bad practice to use out parameters with web services as described in

[Is it bad practice to have an output parameter in a method in a WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733712/is-it-bad-practice-to-have-an-output-parameter-in-a-method-in-a-wcf-service)
Sometimes if we use out parameters in SOAP scenario. The client definition generated from wsdl changes the order of parameters as discussed here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/48b5992f-f7bd-4b67-8299-514d1780fa9a
what i have come to believe is that out parameters are impossible to work with in REST (webHttpBinding). Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bad practice to use out parameters at all in code. It makes code less readable and more error prone. 
You should always think about creating a returning object if you need more than 1 parameter back from a method. (in c# 4 you also can choose to return a tuple).

Comment: +1 for tuple. can you confirm that out parameters are not supported in rest services.

Comment: you can use but it will be moved as first parameter, but it's a really bad practice. Try to avoid it.

Comment: If i use it in rest how would i pass an out parameter when calling this service from browser